# How to share screen with agora.io sdk in android?

Tags: java, android, agora.io, screensharing

i have implemented video calling functionality in agora but i am stuck on how to do screen sharing with agora.io android sdk .
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look at this documentation: https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/screensharing_android?platform=Android.

Basically, you need to use "pushExternalVideoFrame" method. https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/java/classio_1_1agora_1_1rtc_1_1_rtc_engine.html#a6e7327f4449800a2c2ddc200eb2c0386